# How to use Python to ensure a string is only numbers and then convert it to an integer

Tags: python

If i have a string like this: `asdf5493`

I need the last four digits and i get it by doing this:

```
strVar[-4:]
```

Is it possible to then see if they are all numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Convert a string to an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508861/python-convert-a-string-to-an-integer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
strVar[-4:].isdigit()
```

tests if all four characters are digits.  [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

**EDIT:** If your actual goal is to convert this number to an integer, the usual idiom in Python is to just try to do this, and catch the exception in case it fails:

```
s = strVar[-4:]
try:
    i = int(s)
except ValueError:
    # handle the case that it isn't all digits
```

Comment: oh great ok, so if then it is 12.3, it will still fail this call correct?

Comment: A dot isn't a digit, so it will return `False`.

Comment: yes, it would fail with '12.3', if you need to contemplate that case you could just use `try` and catch the exception.

Comment: +1 Nice answer.  I like the way you show both the EAPF style and the LBYL style using *str* methods.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: This was written before Sven's own edit to his answer. Similar in essence but this version with cope with the `.` as well.

---

Are you trying to check if the last four characters are all **digits** or if the last four characters form a **number**?

If it is the first case, Sven's answer is what you are looking for. If it is the latter, here's way you can do the check:

```
def test_last_four(string):
    try:
        float(string[-4:])
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

HTH!

Comment: I think the comment to my answer was just to ensure that `isdigit()` would rule out a decimal point as well.  The OP asked explicitly how to convert to an integer, not a floating point number.

Comment: @SvenMarnach - Interesting, when I answered, there was only the first comment to your question (without your reply nor edit) and I took the comma as being part of the English sentence like in: "So if roses are red, what colour are violets?". NP anyhow... I didn't want to steal your thunder, just clarify why a nearly identical answer is below yours! :)

Comment: Well, my edit was several minutes before you answered -- just look in the logs.

Comment: @SvenMarnach - As you probably have noticed, SO doesn't work real-time, so no notification was shown to me during the edit of my answer.   And yet, although similar our answers are not the same so there's room for both of us! :)

Comment: I don't mind.  My first comment above wasn't because of the similar answers -- it was because of the discripancy between the question title ("convert it to an integer") and your post ("cope with the . as well").