# How does Python interpreter convert a string with whitespaces to an integer?

Tags: python, casting

I learn of converting a string to an integer from [Python: Convert a string to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508861/python-convert-a-string-to-an-integer). But I was still wondering how this works, casting a string consisting of a number following line breaks, like `'5\r\n'`, into `int`.

```
>>> int(' \r \n 5 \r \n ')
5
```

What does Python interpreter do, like this?

```
>>> s = ' \r \n 5 \r \n '
>>> new_s = s.strip()
>>> int(new_s)
5
```

Comment: `int` ignores heading or trailing whitespace. This is a feature, see `help(int)`: *The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded by whitespace.*

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I don't think my question is duplicated as [Python: Convert a string to an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508861/python-convert-a-string-to-an-integer). I am asking how Python interpreter does, the mechanism rather than the policy.

Comment: I don't think the Python interpreter messes with stripping the whitespace. It should be just ignoring it while parsing the expression.

Comment: If you really want to know, [use the Source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/).