# Remove whitespace between strings in a list using Python

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have a list of integer strings to sort. The format is like this:

```
l= ['17', '23', '35', '79', .....]
```

I need to convert each numeric string into an integer so that I can sort their numeric value. I have tried the following,

```
l.sort(key=int)
```

However, I got

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

I think it is due to the whitespace in between the strings. Is that correct? If so, how do I solve it?

Comment: Can you please give an example input that causes this issue?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508861/python-convert-a-string-to-an-integer

Comment: Weird, i try your code it did works, space should not be an issue, check your input list whether it contain something that is not numeric or empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove blank strings from a list:

```
l = filter(str.strip, l)
```

Then you can sort as you were.

Comment: @cdarke: It directly solves the OP's problem.  I think you just haven't thought about how.

Comment: @cdarke it's not... Blank strings raise the OP's exception and this answer filters those out...

Comment: However if you're going to use filter @John I'd avoid the lambda and use str.strip directly.

Comment: @LijieZhou: Great.  Please note that you can "accept" an answer by clicking the checkmark on the left if it solved your problem.