# Python 3 Find if String can be converted to integer before converting

Tags: python, pyautogui

I searched and found ways to check the type of an object but that will not help me in this case.  I need to find out if a string CAN be changed to an Integer before actually doing it.  I am using pyautogui to grab a region of the screen and save it, then pytesseract open the image, read it, and convert it into a string.  Ultimately it is an equation that I would like to solve so then I must change the string into an integer (done in my second function below).  At times pytesseract does not read the image correctly so instead of saying something like 5 + 4 it ends up with something like 5 - H,  so when my code attempts to turn H into an integer it crashes.

**My Question:** How can I check to see if for example `equation[0]` can be made an integer before actually running `int(equation[0])` on it and causing my script to crash?

**My Code:** Simplified greatly to only show the needed lines:

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps
import pytesseract
import pyautogui
import sys
import time

# --- functions ---

def get_text(image):
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='-psm 6')

def get_int(image):
    return int(get_text(image).replace(',', ''))

# --- main ---

     #Is equation= needed below or can it be removed?
equation = pyautogui.screenshot('equation.png',region=(845, 262, 240, 85))
img = Image.open('equation.png')
equation = get_text(img)
print ('Equation:',equation)

#Numbers are always single digit (ex. 9-7=) Use slicing to pull numbers and symbol
firstnum = int(equation[0])
sign = equation[1]
secondnum = int(equation[2])

#Adition and Subtraction are the only options
if sign == '-':
    answer = firstnum - secondnum
if sign =="+":
    answer = firstnum + secondnum
```

EDIT:
Try and Except seems to be a good way to handle this.  Can I somehow turn this into a loop though so it can be checked multiple times.  I have found someone used `while true` as a loop and put try except inside, I am not sure if is will work for me though?  Here is how I THINK my Try Except should look?  If possible I would like to loop the try until it does not hit an exception.

```
try:
    firstnum = int(equation[0])
except:
    equation = pyautogui.screenshot('equation.png',region=(845, 262, 240, 85))
    img = Image.open('equation.png')
    equation = get_text(img)
    firstnum = int(equation[0])
```

Comment: Do you know how to use `try`? You should `try` to parse it, then catch the exception if it fails. (One of) Python's motto(s) is "it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission". Let it fail, then clean it up if it does. I'd make that an answer, but my breaks almost over.

Comment: The type of the object isn't a help if it's a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Convert a string to an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508861/python-convert-a-string-to-an-integer)

Comment: Use exception handling...

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. Look at `equation = pyautogui.screenshot('equation.png',region=(845, 262, 240, 85))` and that is never used, then `equation = get_text(img)`. So it's redefined. Are you sure you're trying to index the right thing?

Comment: @roganjosh I believe you are correct in the fact that I may not need equation= on that line.

Comment: @Brandon: is there some reason to believe that repeating the steps will get you a different character from **get_text**?  Where does the first difference in processing appear?  For example, will the screen shot be the same on the next call?

Comment: To answer your question about retrying in a loop, just stick the `try`/`catch` in a loop and `break` from the loop on success.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the check is simple if this is a single digit:

```
if equation[0] in "0123456789":
    firstnum = int(equation[0])
```

The actual checking function for full-string integer-ness is **isdigit**.

```
if equation[0].isdigit():
    firstnum = int(equation[0])
```

Another possibility is to catch the exception:

```
try:
    firstnum = int(equation[0])
except ... # you now have enough info to look this up.
```

---

**Solution to Looping Problem**

See [here](/questions/18862124/how-to-let-the-user-input-as-many-lines-of-input-as-they-want-until-they-input-t) for one example of how to code those loops in general.

In your specific case, you will want to use only the statements needed to get a different result from **get_text**.  Does taking a new screen shot really give you a different result?  Does *anything* change the result?  Are you guaranteed that you will eventually get a digit?  If not, then you also need a break-out clause, such as giving up after seven failed attempts.

The new code would look something like the code below.  Please change your variables to meaningful names.  Most of all, using **equation** everywhere you can really hurts your program's readability.

```
... 
scan_result = get_text(img)
dgt = scan_result[0]
fail_count = 0
while not dgt.isdigit() and fail_count < 7:
    fail_count += 1
    pyautogui.screenshot('equation.png',region=(845, 262, 240, 85))
    img = Image.open('equation.png')
    scan_result = get_text(img)
    dgt = scan_result[0]

if fail_count >= 7:
    print ("I can't read that number")
else:
    num1 = int(dgt)
```

Also, note that you might want to extract both digits, and run this in a loop over the two separate digits you find.  Can you manage that part on your own now?  Something like:

```
digits = scan_result[0] + scan_result[-1]
for dgt in digits:
    ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need `all(isdigit,...)`? Doesn't `isdigit` accept a single char?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: No, it operates on the entire string.

Comment: Good point ... but the application has only single-digit numbers.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense with the initial code. Look at `equation = pyautogui.screenshot('equation.png',region=(845, 262, 240, 85))` and that is never used, then `equation = get_text(img)`. So it's redefined.

Comment: @roganjosh: Please move the above comment to the main question.  You're correct, so OP (and everyone else) should have it in the main section, not hidden under my answer.

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry im still learning.  I have noticed guys always make statements like that into equations so I did the same here.  could I simply drop equation= and just have it say pyautogui.screenshot('equation.png',region=(845, 262, 240, 85)) ?

Comment: All 3 of the examples in the answer seem great, but I guess I should have slightly edited my question, because if these fail I am just going to have my program go through the steps again and retry.  Is there some way I could build this into a loop instead of an if statement?

Comment: Edited my OP, please check it out guys

Comment: @Brandon: your comments about the question itself belong above, with the question.  Don't hide them down here under my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That's kind of an odd name though. 'digit' suggests 1 character.

Comment: You specifically said that you're looking for a single digit in each such check.

Answer (score 1):

You should `try` then `except`.

But if you really want to catch it ahead of time, consider a regex. `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`, so numbers can be matched as `[-+]?\d+`.

If numbers are always a single digit, just use `x in "0123456789"`

Comment: Could I somehow turn try and accept into a loop? So that it can be checked multiple times?  Editing my main question now to throw out there what I mean.

Comment: It depends what you want to do on a failure. I assume that pyautogui.screenshot is not a randomized algorithm and so I'd assume that if it fails once, it'll always fail.

Comment: I have checked the output of the pyautogui file and I can clearly read the equation myself.  It is an issue with pytesseract reading it, so my thought was to just take a new fresh image with pyautogui and let pytesseract read it again.

Comment: I would assume that it reads each picture the same way every time. Maybe you can train it or tell it that it should only attempt to read certain characters

Comment: That is a really good thought. I had a really hard time finding any info on pytesseract.